# Using Cloudflare SSL Free Service under Domain with Yandex DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

I have domain using Yandex DNS

mydomain.com
DNS Primary : dns1.yandex.net
DNS Secondary : dns2.yandex.net

I used DNS yandex, because they have Mail for domain services, and it was a must procedure to full integrated using their DNS record, so i can use custom CNAME for accessing email for my user like http://mail.mydomain.com

But after, it switch from using dns record cloudflare to yandex, my domain has lost capability to use the Cloudflare free ssl services.

i'm already trying entry both DNS Cloudflare to A and NS record under yandex dns editor, but is not changed anything.

So it is possible, to get capability to may domain using cloudflare free ssl again ?

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free service at cloudflare requires you to use their nameservers. If you go for a paid plan ($20 per month as of April 2016) you can ask for a CNAME setup that allows you to use your own, or in this case yandex, nameservers.

More info:

- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202320534-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-without-changing-my-nameservers-to-CloudFlare-
- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168706-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup-

I would recommend that you change to their DNS service.

Comment: this effective vendor lock-in is another great reason not to use https for non-commerce web-sites.

Comment: This answer is not correct! Yes, you can!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if in the past this was not possible (as per other answers), but, now, in 2018 it is

- Keep the DNS servers pointed to Cloudflare.
- verify the domain creating the CNAME in Cloudflare DNS - The trick here is bypass Cloudflare JUST for this record. Click on the orange cloud and make it gray.
- create the MX records in Cloudflare (Skips Cloudflare by default)

You're good to go!